# Popup menu that overlaps triggered item

Tags: android

I need to create a popup menu with list where selected item exactly overlaps previously selected item. This behavior is described here [Material design recommendations/Simple Menus](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/menus.html#menus-simple-menus)

Is there some class/view that already implements that behavior?

I need to support 19th API and higher
Positioning of popup menu is important (as recommended by Material design)

Comment: You can pretty much do that with a spinner and using a dropdownmenu.

Comment: It is quite close to that I need but proposed solution doesn't consider positioning of shown popup window (as it is recommended by Material design).It should be added manually

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a popup window : [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html)